# Silent variable assignment

Tags: mysql, sql, client

How can I silence only variable assignments when using `mysql` from `mysql-client`?

I have a file `sql.sql`:

```
select id := id from companies where name="StackExchange";
select profit, companyID from profits where companyID=@id
select easter from egg where easterEgg=@id
```

If I run `mysql < sql.sql`, I get

```
@id = id
12

profit   companyID
------   ---------
-12000   12

easter
------
egg
expires
April
```

I want everything except the variable assignment lines:

```
profit   companyID
------   ---------
-12000   12

easter
------
egg
expires
April
```

I want to avoid repeating code many times if I write

```
select profit, companyID from profits where companyID=(select id from companies where name="StackExchange")
select easter from egg where easterEgg=(select id from companies where name="StackExchange")
select something_else from someTable where this_column=(select id from companies where name="StackExchange")
```

Comment: Try: `mysql --silent < sql.sql`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with temporary Variables, this doesn't output the result because it copies it into the session variable.

```
SELECT id INTO @id FROM companies WHERE name="StackExchange";
SELECT profit, companyID FROM profits WHERE companyID=@id;
SELECT easter FROM egg WHERE easterEgg=@id;
```